Is it possible to calculate the odds of success for each component in a network?
I am trying to compare various workflow plans that have previously been reported in literature. The outcome is always a binary of "success" or "failure". Different reports have different combinations of these treatments.
For example:
Treatment1 + Treatment3 + Treatment1 + Treatment2 = Success

Treatment2 = Failure

Treatment3 + Treatment2 = Failure

Treatment3 + Treatment3 + Treatment1 = Success

and so on with nine other treatment types.
I can make network graphs in R using the igraph package with this data, but I want to somehow calculate the success odds of each pair of treatment like:
Treatment1 + Treatment3
Treatment2 + Treatment1
How do I do this?
